# Adding an object stored in a variable to another object without specifying a key is using the variable name as the key. Is this expected behavior?

Tags: javascript, object

I was building an object parameter structure to use for a plugin's initialization.  The specific plugin or structure doesn't matter but lets say it was something simple like the following:

```
{
   key1:'val1',
   key2: {
      subkey1: 'subval1'
   }
}
```

I was building the overall structure in two different object variables, like so:

```
var key2 = {subkey1: 'subval1'};

var finalStructure = {
   key1: 'val1',
   key2  <-- oops! instead of key2: key2
};
```

I didn't realize until later that I had forgotten to specify the 'key2:' key and was surprised that the overall structure did indeed end up with `key2: {...}`.

I changed the variable name of key2 to foobar and the resulting structure used the variable name 'foobar' for the name of the key.

```
var foobar = {subkey1: 'subval1'};

var finalStructure = {
   key1: 'val1',
   foobar
};
```

resulted in this structure:

```
{
   key1:'val1',
   foobar: {
      subkey1: 'subval1'
   }
}
```

**Is this documented and expected behavior; safe to do? Or is this a lucky bug that happens to cause javascript to behave this way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this documented and expected behavior; safe to do?

Yes, they're [shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). If you only put the variable name, the object will take the variable name as the property name, then assign it the value held by that variable.

```
// Shorthand property names (ES2015)
var a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
var o = {a, b, c};

console.log(o); // {a:'foo', b: 42, c: {}}

// The long, and quite redundant, route:
var o = { a: a, b: b, c: c }
```